# Get AAVE LendingPool address using Vyper interface contract

Tags: dapps, defi, aave

I'm at the very early stages of trying to understand how to send coins to AAVE. I've coded the following which is the first step to get the pool address from the proxy contract.

```
from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

lendingpool: address

interface aave:
    def getLendingPool() -> address: nonpayable

@external
def __init__():
    self.lendingpool = aave(0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5).getLendingPool()

@external
def getPool()->address:
   return self.lendingpool
```

When I try to deploy this in remix, I get Execution Reverted

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally using the Ethereum AAVE address rather than the Polygon AAVE address. Swapping the Ethereum AAVE address for the Polygon contract address solved the issue.

```
from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

lendingpool: address

interface aave:
    def getLendingPool() -> address: nonpayable

@external
def __init__():
    self.lendingpool = aave(0xd05e3E715d945B59290df0ae8eF85c1BdB684744).getLendingPool()

@external
@view
def getPool()->address:
   return self.lendingpool
```